# Element styling from function not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table sort function that can take a few seconds sometimes due to the amount of data.  In order to provide users with a visual cue, I've added a spinner gif in a hidden div.  The sort function is supposed to style the div to display block and then return it to display none when finished.  This didn't work... so I created a separate function (below) that still doesn't work (tried both MS Edge and Chrome).

Function:

```
function showhidesortdiv(bool, starttime) {
  var starttime, endtime;
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("sort_shade");
  if (bool) {
    console.log("Sort started");
    mydiv.style.display = "block";
    console.log("Display: " + mydiv.style.display);
    return starttime = new Date();
  } else { 
    console.log("Sort ended"); 
    mydiv.style.display = "none";
    console.log("Display: " + mydiv.style.display);
    endtime = new Date(); 
    console.log("Sort duration: " + (endtime - starttime));
  }
}
```

CSS for the div:

```
#sort_shade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Console output is:

```
Sort started
Display: block
Sort ended
Display: none
Sort duration: 2616
```

It's worth noting that manually typing
`'document.getElementById("sort_shade").style.display = "block"'`
into the console has the desired effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You should add the HTML markup to your question. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you create a [mcve].

Comment: The issue is that the JS operations will block the main thread. The page is only repainted after the JS has run to completion. This means, CSS and HTML updates won’t be visible until after the end of your JS function.

Comment: If you want to see partial changes to the DOM, you need to execute your code asynchronously, e.g. call `setInterval()` with a function that performs part of the sort.

Comment: If the code that’s supposed to show the spinner blocks, then the browser won’t update the DOM until it’s done and it’s too late. Is there any way to make the sorting function asynchronous?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.  I'll look into the async and setinterval.  I would have thought it would work because showhidesortdiv() is called from inside my sort function.